# Current Visible item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, exoplayer

I want to find the current visible item/items in Vertical Linear layout (RecyclerView), So that I can attach Exoplayer to the top most element rather than all the items. And even play that item on visibility. I am not able to find any idea to this implement this.

Should this be handled in Fragment or Adapter.

Thanks, I am new to Android development.

Comment: How many elements do you have? Maybe it'd be better to use `RecyclerView` instead of `LinearLayout`? BTW why you have Adapter in this case?

Comment: I have RecyclerView with vertical linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

In LinearLayoutManager, you can use some methods which they can help.

```
layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

These returns position as integer. You can use like below:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```

But you should note that, in some cases, **findFirstVisibleItemPosition()** in some devices not worked stable for me. For example, it was working at Sony, LG and Samsung devices, but same code, didn't worked at Nexus 5. I am not sure why it did not worked, but I changed my approach because of this bug.

Comment: What approach did you pick after?

Comment: @user1590595 it was a different and complex feature about scrolling consuming behaviour with CollapsableToolbarLayout. I managed to fix that with custom fling behaviour. I do not think it is related to your case. It needs too much to explain.